# Generating custom forms from DB schema

Tags: python, django, django-forms, pylons, web2py

I am a current web2py user, but find I still go back to Django once in a while (where I started). Specifically when working on projects where I want to make use of some specific django apps/plugins/extensions that don't yet exist in web2py.

One thing that I can't live without in web2py, which I am looking for a solution for in Django, is the way to create html forms from a db table and being able to then customize their look and layout in the view, without javascript.

Key things I am looking for:

1. Generate html form from a db table
2. Assign custom css classes/ids to each field in the generated html form (js disabled)
3. Place each form field/element in a pre-made html view via a method call in the view

i.e.

**I have a table A. In web2py I can do (in controller):**

```
def display_form():
   form = SQLFORM(db.table_A)
   #Can I do the following in Django? Assign custom CSS to each form field?
   form.element(_name='email')['_class'] = = "custom_css_classes, list"

   if form.accepts(request.vars, session):
       response.flash = 'form accepted'
   elif form.errors:
       response.flash = 'form has errors'
   else:
       response.flash = 'please fill out the form'
   return dict(form=form)
```

**Then, in the View I can do:**

```
form.custom.start
form.custom.widget.name
form.custom.widget.email
form.custom.widget.form_field_name
           ...
<div class="span-5 last"><input type="submit" class="register_btn" value="Sign Up"></input></div>
form.custom.end
```

The above takes a DB table, creates an HTML form, and then lets me stick each separate form field in any place in the pre-made HTML that I want (using those "custom" method calls on the passed "form" object. Including the custom css classes I assigned to each separate field of the generated html form.

See documentation for details on the above code:

http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06?search=define_table

http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07?search=sqlform#SQLFORM

http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/05?search=#Server-side-DOM-and-Parsing

http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07?search=form.custom

How do I do the above in Django without dirtying my javascript with layout hacks. Assume javascript is disabled in the browsers where I need my app to run. Furthermore, I would love to make use of Django admin. Pylons solutions also welcome!

Links to articles/tutorials/howtos for this would be greatly appreciated.
Also, please make an equivalent result of the above code using the method you mention in your response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ModelForm` and override any field you wanna customize by explicitly declaring them.

If you want to set field attributes like `class` and `id`, you need to do something like this:

```
name = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special'}))
```

In case you are interested, you may change the order of the fields by specifying a `fields` sequence in your `Meta` class:

```
class Meta:
    model = YourModel
    fields = ('title', 'content')
```

You may read the full documentation here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

Comment: Additional documentation/example at: http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/653af4944d904562/ff467e7e752efd89?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=Custom+CSS+for+newforms+using+ModelForm#ff467e7e752efd89

Comment: You can do exactly the same with web2py in one line:

    db.mytable.myfield.widget=lambda f,v:SQLFORM.widgets.string.widget(f,v,_class='special')

Comment: And didn't you notice that I break the line of code into two line just for readability?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, take a look at Django's [ModelForm](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform). I am assuming that you have models mapped to the tables in question. Vanilla `ModelForm` instances will work without JS. However `ModelForm`s are usually defined ahead of time and not constructed on the fly. I suppose they can be created on the fly but that would be a bit tricky.

Comment: Couldn't see anything in the documentation about specifying css for the generated form fields...did I miss it somewhere?